# Did Windows LiveID finally every get integrated into OpenID?

Tags: openid, windows-live-id

Two or three years ago, Microsoft announced that they were going to support OpenID with LiveID. I can't find an OpenID url for Microsoft anywhere. Did they scrap the idea? What happened? Is there an OpenID url for Microsoft Live I'm not aware of?